# What is best way to import "exceljs" lib to angular

Tags: angular, npm, import, angular7, exceljs

I'm using exceljs(https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs) to import and export excel file in an angular 7 app. Here is how I import it :
`import {Workbook} from "exceljs";`even if it work perfectly but after build production and look at main.js by `source-map-explorer` it has taken 483kb(20%) in node_modules, too large I think.

does anyone have any solution to reduce the size of `exceljs`in node_modules ?

Answer (score 2):

The size in node_modules does not matter because not everything is put into the bundles. But if you want to reduce the bundle sizes you can exclude the library from the vendor bundle by loading the library via cdn and not including it in the project:

1. Import the type definitions to make exceljs available in your editor [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/exceljs)
2. Import the sources from [cdn](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/exceljs) (via index.html)
3. Remove the exceljs npm package from your project

That does not lower the all in all size but it makes your vendor bundle smaller. Hope that answers your question. Hope this helps...

Comment: Nice solution, this works for me, exceljs is a pretty good tool, but can be dangerous for performance ...